# Add top caret (triangle) to UL?

Tags: css, geometry, html-lists

So basically I have a vertical 'UL' list. It's a dropdown from a div that is enabled on click, how can I draw one of those facebook/twitter triangles on top of it?

HTML:

```
<div id="set">
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li>Privacy</li>
                        <li>Info</li>
                        <li>Logout</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 5%;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown:before{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.dropdown li{
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[image]

Should I try using relative position on the triangle or? .. any ideas?

Comment: What is a "top carrot"?

Comment: this http://puu.sh/4mH7n/b3fce7d966.jpg little triangle on the top of dropdown menus

Comment: @AndersonGreen Looking at the picture I would imagine the OP means "caret" and is referring to the thing like a callout or speech bubble where it looks like it is pointing to the place the menu came from.

Comment: @lc. I feel like such an idiot! lmao carrot? xD

Comment: good example here mate http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles

Comment: @user1525612 thanks worked great!

Comment: This website http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/ generates the CSS for these speech bubble arrows for you. It can be a bit of a time saver.